# ¿Cuál es el consumo de cuotas diarias en google app script trabajando con html y javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script

Quiero agregar un documento html - javascript a mi proyecto en GAS, este documento html-js debe realizar varias consultas con Fetch API y luego pasar a una hoja en sheet. Si un proceso de consultas en el html-js se tarda 7 minutos o si realizo varias consultas en un día que superan los 90 minutos en total, esto afecta a mi [cuota diaria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) en app script? O en general los procesos realizados en html-js como consultas, lecturas, creación de archivos, van a afectar a mi cuota diaria de GAS?

Answer (score 0):

No existe tal cosa como "cuota diaria de GAS" pero existen cuotas y limitaciones específicas, por ejemplo, para el número de llamadas fetch hay una cuota, el tiempo máximo de ejecución de un script tiene un límite. Algunas de estas cuotas y límites dependen del tipo de cuenta.

Las creación de archivos depende del tipo de archivo del que se trate y del tipo de cuenta, por ejemplo hay límite para creación de presentaciones, documentos y hojas de cálculo de los editores de Google, 250 de cada tipo para cuentas gratuitas y para cuentas de Google Workspace varía dependiendo del tipo. También hay cuotas para la conversión de archivos.

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas